# Why was an edit removing all bold text formatting rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, reject-reasons

I recently suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34989185) that removes the bold formatting that was applied to all the text of an answer and fixes some minor typos and language errors. It was approved by one user and rejected by two. I made sure to re-read my edit to see if I introduced some language or formatting errors, but couldn't find any. What should I do in this case?

Comment: Imho: Two quite new reviewers made a wrong choice

Comment: It does leave rather large grammatical errors uncorrected. I might have accepted and Improved Edit but I can see it reasonable to also reject.

Comment: Oh wow. That entire Q&A has... issues.

Comment: Not quite related to editing that post but...it doesn't make any sense. That's not a language issue, just the code doesn't even do what the description claims. Nor does the description tie in with the code. It talks about overriding a constructor but nothing like this happens. And the code seems to compile fine, not show an error as the text claims. Boggles the mind how that has *three upvotes*.

Comment: @VLAZ I didn't notice the disagreement between the code and the description at first, as the latter was sufficient for me to understand how would the compiler react to trying to override a constructor. Perhabs this was also the case for those who upvoted the answer. They didn't need to read the code.

Comment: One possibility is reviewers only looked at the rendered view, which does not accurately represent the diff (it only shows the holding change, nothing else).

Comment: @MehdiCharife I mean only the first sentence is right. All the rest is wrong. Trying to match the constructor name of the parent and that being a method is a red herring. It's not at all the reason why constructor overriding is not possible. You *can* have the super and sub class with the same name - if they reside in different packages: `class Foo extends com.other.Foo {}` That won't make the constructor overriding possible. Methods and constructors are simply not trivially interchangeable.

Comment: I don't know. I would have approved it.

Comment: @nobody That's a really good callout; it's pretty unfortunate that removing the bold highlights the entire block in the diff and hides the specific changes within; at first glance it looks like basically nothing changed other than the bold... but I'd also argue that reviewers should be paying better attention than that, too.

Comment: I made a further attempt to improve the grammar in the answer, because the grammar was really quite poor (and there was some redundancy). However, the answer seems bad anyway: the example doesn't actually appear to show an attempt to override a constructor; and if the description says that the compiler will complain and require something, it should show the form that the constructor complains about, not a fixed form.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel *"the compiler treats the attempt at an overridden constructor as a method rather than a constructor"* I find this wording very unnatural and confusing. The OP didn't intend to say that the compiler treats the attempt at overriding the constructor as a method, but as an attempt to override a method.

Comment: Yes, I like your wording better and approved it. But I also cast a delete vote (and several more) - good lord there are a lot of awful answers there.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Unfortunately, the other reviewer (a moderator) [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34995218) it.

Comment: Side note: if you are digging out random ancient questions to make mostly cosmetic updates I'd avoid bringing it up on meta :)... as it may look like you are doing it strictly to gain points (and/or clog the review queue).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't think the post in question is in any way random. It asks a FAQ question, and it was the first that popped up after I googled whether it was possible to override a constructor. Most of the editing that I do relates to Q&As concerning questions that I myself look for answers to.

Comment: If the edit suggestion queue had a majority of entries of this quality we would be in a much better place. 90% of them are much worse.

Comment: Looks totally random to me :). I randomly checked several of your recent edits and all are on ancient posts on mix of tech. It looks like this particular case did not get other people looking at history of OP's edits... but in general I'd add some language along the lines of "I was researching XXXXX and found several post with poor formatting" if indeed that is the reason for finding the posts (all edits are welcome indeed, but some people go overboard creating unneeded work for reviewers... and it is not always easy to distinguish edits on post found during research vs. edit farming).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The fact that my edits cover posts from different technologies doesn't necessarily mean that my basis for selecting those posts was random. I've been reading on design patterns and object-oriented design lately, and these subjects tend to be illustrated in a number of different languages and technologies. I'm also working on an ML project in C in which OOP is emulated, which partly explains the C edits.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm also starting to consider the possibility of using jUnit to test my C project using the Java Native Interface, since the current testing framework that I'm using (Criterion) seems to be lacking in many respects (and I'd also like to get my hands a bit dirty on Java). I'm not sure however since this might not be practical.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov For instance, a noise-reducing [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34898640) that I made on a very old post (13 years old) could be shown to happen after the fact a user recommended the same post to me in [softwareengineering.meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/is-asking-whether-the-java-collection-framework-is-an-example-where-favour-com)

Comment: @MehdiCharife If you decide to make that brave choice, use JNA ("Java Native Access"), not JNI :) JNI is old as dirt and was always a maintenance nightmare. JNA is more straightforward.

Comment: I must be missing something obvious, I can't even find the answer, that Mehdi proposed an edit to.  I see the edit proposal itself, but the answer, does not appear.  Which suggests it's be deleted. As to the accuracy of the code, the fact it compiles but does nothing, suggests ChatGPT.

Comment: @SecurityHound the answer was from 2015, definitely not GenAI. Just regular human… output.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - I wouldn't know because I can't determine when the answer was submitted because it appears to have been deleted

Comment: @SecurityHound [screenshot of the deleted answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uRh4.png). People have been wrong before ChatGPT existed.

Comment: @VLAZ at least now we have an excuse - if it is wrong - blame ChatGPT, if it is correct than I wrote it :)... Was much harder life *back then*.